# Calling a method within a method using polymorphism?

Tags: java

I need to call the move() method within the play() method using polymorphism. I am not sure how to do that. Everything else in my programs works correctly my only problem is how to use the move() method in the play() method. Move() method is in another class called "Humans" that also uses the "player" interface. That method works correctly.

```
public interface Players {
    int move();   // returns an int that is given by user    
}
// Method that I need call the move() method in
// You may ignore the rest of the code expect where I commented 
class Nim implements Players {
    private int marbles = 0;
    private int take = 0;
    public void play() {
        playerName = obj2.getName();
        System.out.println("Player " + playerName);
        turn();
        getComp();
        int removeMarbles = 0;
        System.out.println("\nNumber of marbles: " + marbles);
        Pile obj = new Pile();
        while (marbles > 0) {
            if (turn % 2 != 0) {
                take = move() // need to call move method using polymorphism, ***code does not work just to show where I need help
                System.out.println(playerName + " took " + take + " marble(s)");
                marbles = marbles - take;
                System.out.println("There are " + marbles + " marbles left.");
            }

            if (turn % 2 == 0) {
                if (compName.equals("Dumb")) {
                    removeMarbles = (int)(Math.random() * (marbles / 2) + 1);
                    System.out.println("\nThe computer took " + removeMarbles + " marble(s)");
                    marbles -= removeMarbles;
                }

                if (compName.equals("Smart")) {
                    int pile = marbles;
                    int power = 2;
                    if (marbles <= power) {
                        removeMarbles = 1;
                    }
                    if (marbles > power) {
                        while (power < marbles) {
                            power = power * 2;
                        }
                        removeMarbles = ((power / 2) - 1);
                    }
                    marbles = removeMarbles;
                    System.out.println("\nThe computer took " + (pile - removeMarbles) + " marble(s)");
                }
                System.out.println("There are " + marbles + " marbles left.\n");
            }

            if (marbles == 0) {
                if (turn % 2 != 0) {
                    System.out.println("\nThe computer is the winner!!!!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("\n" + playerName + " is the winner!!!!");
                }
            }
            turn++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Interfaces are contracts describing the group of related methods with empty bodies.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) You need to implement the `move()` method in your child class,and then overwrite the method with any additional functionality:

```
public int move(){

  // Implements interface .move();
   System.out.println("Nim .move()");
}
```

From the [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html)

If you want to implement the method in Players, you cannot implement it as an interface, because the behavior will be overwritten by the method implementing the interface. You should instead consider an abstract class structure, with the `super` keyword:

From the [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This didn't work for me. It gives me an error when I call super.move();

Comment: Because you are implementing `Players` as an interface, not an abstract class. If you want to use concrete behavior defined in `Players`, you must declare it as an abstract class, then use `super.move()`. However, this will limit you to single inheritance.

Comment: Yeah I can't do it will ruin the rest of my program. But thanks for your help.

Comment: Then just implement the functionality in `Players.move()` in `Nim.move()` not great coding style, but if that is your restriction.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to implement that method in Humans class as per below

```
public class Humans implements Players {
   public int move(){
       // your logic here
   }
}
```

then you can call that method by using object as follow

```
Players  ob = new Humans();
take = ob.move();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any other way to do this. I am not allowed to use Players  ob = new Humans(); in my code. It is a restriction on my assignment.

Comment: One option is you can use  Humans ob = new Humans() else you have to implement  that method in Nim  class.

Answer (score -1):

Currently, your move() is being declared as a variable. You'll want to make it a method in the interface, so you can call it without casting.

basically,

```
int move();
```

should look something like:

```
public int move(){
  // your code here;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The thing is I want to use the move() method of my other class in my Nim class. I am not sure how what you did will help.

Comment: actually his use of move(); is correct (at last in this instance). You cannot put any code inside of a method in an interface declaration. You merely indicate what methods will be present, and leave the implementation of the methods to the classes that use the interface. This is one of the main differences between interfaces and classes